# Define custom keys only for eshell

Tags: key-bindings, eshell

I'm struggling to find a way to define keys only for eshell. Looking at the emacs wiki I saw examples using the `eshell-mode-map` yet I get errors when trying to define it.

> progn: Symbol’s value as variable is void: eshell-mode-map

I'm trying to get the f-keys to work as nornal f-keys after using them to quick launch functions in global mode.

Here is what I tried

```
(define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") (kbd "<f9>")  )
```

Comment: I'm confused by the use of `(kbd "<f9>") (kbd "<f9>")` (which will cause an infinite loop). Ignoring the specific code, what is the desired result? What is `<f9>` currently doing (and in which specific scenario)?, and what do you need it to do?

Comment: According to the comments on [@xuchunyang's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30385/5296), I think the idea is to send `<f9>` to a program running in `term`, which probably requires using escape codes somehow.

Answer (score 3):

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") #'emacs-version)))
```

Comment: thx @xuchunyang. i tried that but that results in ```<f9> is undefined``` when trying to issue 'f9' in a terminal app. thx Z

Comment: @zeltak What do you mean by 'terminal app'? `eshell` and `term` are two different things in Emacs.

Comment: @tyler. lets say htop when run from eshell. thx Z.

Comment: @zeltak htop doesn't run in eshell. It will run in term, is that what you mean?

Comment: @zeltak htop will not run (I mean it doesn't produce correct output) under eshell because it requires a terminal device, unless you put `htop` into `eshell-visual-commands` in your own Emacs init file. When htop runs in term, you can try `term-raw-map` (which is used in "char mode") or `term-mode-map` (which is used in "line mode").

Comment: thx @xuchunyang. yes its under eshell-visual-commands and runs great as far as i can tell. i just cant get `<f9>` to work still :D

Comment: @zeltak Ah I see! This is a tricky one - eshell visual commands are not actually run in an eshell buffer, because eshell can't handle the visual formatting directly. Instead, eshell starts a term mode buffer and runs the command there. So your htop process *is* running in term mode, even though you call it from eshell. So you need to modify the term-mode key map.

Comment: hmm thx @Tyler. so i tried both this `(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") #'emacs-version ) ` and this `(add-hook 'term-mode-hook          (lambda ()  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") #'emacs-version)))` yet can get f9 to work :D. any clue how to try and get this working?

Comment: @zeltak For `term-mode-map`, you need to switch to "line mode" to get f9 work. `term` uses "char mode" at the beginning, in this mode, `term-raw-map` should work.

Comment: thx @xuchunyang. that indeed worked  `(add-hook 'term-mode-hook           (lambda ()  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "<f9>") #'emacs-version)))` :). only thing left is how to actually get the <f9> and not emacs=version :). any clue?